# RecyclerView Android Studio on the Fragment raises a red line

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have this code, which integrates a `RecyclerView` within a Fragment, but this line:

`mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) mRecyclerView.findViewById(R.id.list_data);`

Gives me an error, it tells me that:

```
Unreachable statement
```

And I don't know why, any idea?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
public class KecamatanFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String data_url = "http://xxxxxxxxxx/daftar/get_kecamatan.php"; // kasih link prosesnya

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mManager;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    ArrayList<ModelData> mItems;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_kecamatan, container, false);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) mRecyclerView.findViewById(R.id.list_data); <-- Unreachable statement
        mItems = new ArrayList<>();
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3));
        mAdapter = new AdapterProcess(KecamatanFragment.this, mItems);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        loadjson();
    }
    enter code here
    //proses mengambil data
    private void loadjson(){
        pd.setMessage("Mengambil Data");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();

        JsonArrayRequest arrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, data_url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                pd.cancel();
                Log.d("volley", "response : " + response.toString());
                for (int i=0; i < response.length(); i++){
                    try {
                        JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        ModelData md = new ModelData();
                        md.setKecamatan(data.getString("kecamatan")); // memanggil nama array yang kita buat
                        mItems.add(md);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener(){

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                pd.cancel();
                Log.d("volley", "error : " + error.getMessage());
            }
        });
        Controller.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(arrayRequest);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Unreachable statement

That's expected error, because you're stopping the `onCreateView` method after you're giving it a **`return`** statement:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // You've already close the method when you're giving a return
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_kecamatan, container, false);


    // so this won't be reachable, hence the unreachable error raised.
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) mRecyclerView.findViewById(R.id.list_data);

    ...
}
```

So, you either need to inflate the Layout first and bind the view then return the inflated view or move the view binding after the return statement to another method.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by ישו אוהב אותך, You're returning the inflated view immediately. keep a reference to the inflated view and return it at the end. Also, you probably want to use `findViewById` on the inflated view and not on `mRecyclerView`.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_kecamatan, container, false);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_data);
        mItems = new ArrayList<>();
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3));
        mAdapter = new AdapterProcess(KecamatanFragment.this, mItems);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        loadjson();

        return view;
    }
```